# When can I apply for a short stay visa after consuming the 90/180 rule?

Tags: visas, 90-180-visa-rules

The question is in the title basically.

I had consumed 90 days recently, I'm a non EEA national, therefore I have to apply for a visa for my next visit, the question is when should I start the procedure? Do I have to fully wait out 90 more days until I apply or can I apply early to get my visa prior to the 90th day?

Comment: Can you clarify your citizenship m, or at least whether you are a visa national? In other words, did you get a visa for your previous stay? If you didn’t, getting a visa won’t change anything, the 90/180 rule still applies, including across separate visas or stays with and without a visa. If you had a visa, what were the validity/duration, max stay and number of entries?

Comment: The application itsself can be made at any time. Your itinerary should however show that your entry and stay is possible based on the 90 day rule.

Comment: I had a German residence which was my "visa" to Romania, I am just wondering when I should apply for the visit visa to Romania since I have to wait 90 days before revisiting, since it is possible that I apply, get the visa, but cannot go to Romania yet due to the rule, then I would lose some of the C visa days. @jcaron

Comment: That's an interesting question and a bit of a corner case. I would recommend adding all these details to the question, which doesn't fully make sense as written. I think in that case you may apply for a Schengen visa immediately, the German residence permit won't count towards the 90-day short-stay limit and stays in Romania don't count either. That's assuming you want to visit the Schengen area. If you want to return to Romania specifically, it's more complicated.

Comment: Of course, if your goal is to visit Romania, the logic of the system is that you should apply for a *Romanian* visa, not a Schengen visa (even if in practice it grants you an exemption to the visa requirement that's just as good). Maybe that's what you meant? I think everybody thought you meant a Schengen visa as Romania wasn't mentioned…

Comment: @cazanova depending on your citizenship you may not need a visa at all.  There are dozens of non-EEA countries whose citizens do not need a visa for a short stay, including most of the Americas, some of eastern and southern Europe, and most wealthy industrialized countries in Asia and the Pacific.  If you are using the passport of one of those countries then you will not need a visa.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area

Comment: I think you should clarify at least your citizenship, your residence permit situation in Germany (and/or elsewhere) and where you actually want to spend time, as at the moment it is slightly confusing.

Comment: What happened to your German residence?  Have you moved outside of the Schengen area and the EU?  Also, "it is possible that I apply, get the visa, but cannot go to Romania yet due to the rule" is not correct.  If your visa is granted while your 90 days are exhausted, the start date of the visa's validity should be after the 90 days reset.

Answer (score 3):

The general rules and recommendations apply, you should apply for your next short-stay visa around three months before your next trip. That trip however has to occur after 90 days (or wherever you can re-enter while still respecting the 90-days-in-any-180-day-period limit), otherwise the visa should be refused. It's possible to get the new visa earlier (with a period of validity into the future) or to have back-to-back multiple entry visas over several years. But you must still abide by the maximum stay rule no matter what.

On the other hand, if you do not need a visa to enter the Schengen area for a short visit (i.e. your earlier stay was a visa-free stay), there is no point applying for a short-stay visa. You won't get one. The only type of visa open to people who do not need a short-stay visa for a visit are long-stay (national) visas. You can apply for one of those immediately, provided you qualify in some way. The 90/180 rules doesn't apply.

Whatever the case may be, a short-stay visa is not a way to overcome the 90-day limit and the exact same limit applies to short-stay visa holders. It doesn't make sense to write that you must apply for a short-stay visa *because* you have already stayed in the Schengen area for 90 days. Either you need a short-stay visa based on your citizenship (in other words: the stay you mentioned was already under an earlier short-stay visa) and you will always need a short-stay visa. Or you don't and you will never get a short-stay visa.

Comment: After getting the short stay visa, and after the 90 days are over, I can visit Romania and stay there for 90 days even if the visa expires while I am there, correct?

Comment: @cazanova I don't know. My understanding is that you're not even supposed to apply or get a Schengen visa if your only goal is to visit Romania. We should stop talking about “the short-stay visa” and be more specific about which one we mean (Schengen or Romanian). The fact that you were talking about Romania completely eluded me as it wasn't mentioned, you should really add that to the question and I will probably have to delete my answer.

Comment: @cazanova you must leave on or before the visa's expiration date.  If you are a visa national, you should apply for the visa as soon as you leave Romania giving a travel date that is more than 90 days after your departure.  The visa's start date should correspond to your anticipated arrival date.  However, to be certain that your visa will be sufficient for a 90-day stay, you'll have to apply with an itinerary showing that you're planning to stay for 90 days, and that will tend to increase the likelihood that the consulate will decline to grant the visa.

Comment: Rereading your last comment and adding to what @phoog explained, you can only stay for what's allowed by your visa. A visa can have a restricted duration of stay, period of validity, or both. You cannot (generally) stay after the visa expires, no, at least not without applying for something else (say another residence permit).